# Executing a Stored Procedure from C# gives the error Invalid column name 'testTable2'

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a Stored Procedure that creates a table if this tables does NOT EXISTS.

1. The `commented code` can execute this code successfully.

The problem now is that I try to execute this code from `C#`, where I have rewritten the procedure, so I can pass along a parameter: `@tableName sysname` which is the name for the table I try to create: `IF NOT EXISTS`.

However, I receive this error which I don't understand why I get:
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'testTable2'. Invalid column name 'U'.'`

**Code for Stored Procedure:** 
(The commented code works to execute by itself. The code after should be similar but receives the error when executing from C#)

```
--CREATE PROCEDURE createNewTable
--AS

--IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = N'testTable2' AND xtype = N'U')
--BEGIN
--CREATE TABLE testTable2
--(
--    [DateTime]    SMALLDATETIME  NOT NULL,
--    [FeatureNbr]  SMALLINT         NOT NULL,
--    [Value]       FLOAT (53)       NULL,
--    [Bool]        BIT              NULL,
--  CONSTRAINT UC_testTable2 UNIQUE (DateTime),
--  CONSTRAINT PK_testTable2 PRIMARY KEY (FeatureNbr, DateTime)
--);
--END

CREATE PROCEDURE createNewTable
    @tableName sysname

AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @FullQuery nvarchar(1000)
    SET @FullQuery = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' AND xtype=U) ' + 
                   
                     'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' ([DateTime] SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL, [FeatureNbr] SMALLINT NOT NULL, [Value] FLOAT (53) NULL, [Bool] BIT NULL, 
                      CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'UC_',@tableName)) + ' UNIQUE (DateTime), 
                      CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'PK_',@tableName)) + ' PRIMARY KEY (FeatureNbr, DateTime)); ' 
                     
    EXECUTE sp_executesql 
    @FullQuery;
END
```

**C# code:** (Code that executes the `createNewTable` Stored Procedure)

```
        void createNewTable()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("createNewTable", conn); //1. create a command object identifying the stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tableName", "testTable2"));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        static private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\andre\\source\\repos\\TestDatabaseCreation\\DatabaseTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        }
```

Comment: What is `N`? What is Name = `N`'SomeText'. Can't see where its defined

Comment: Have you thought about selecting out the `@FullQuery` (this will show your issue) before executing it, this is what would be executed?

Comment: Have you tried executing your  `stored procedure` in `SSMS` query window ? Make sure it do what you want before executing your `C#` application.

Comment: `N`'SomeText'. The `N` means that the String should be unicode as I have understood it.

Comment: @Squirrel. The code that is commented in the stored procedure do work in the query window and does exactly what it is supposed to do. So I have tried to rewrite this so I can execute this in `C#`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I am not sure how you mean there exactly or what I should try?

Comment: In the query select out your dynamic query so you *can see the query its building*. This is how you can tell where your dynamic is going wrong before executing it. Your dynamic query is wrong.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I am sorry, I am not really sure what I should do exactly there? How will I do this exactly? `select out your dynamic query so you can see the query its building`. Should I delete something from the query?

Comment: If you need a single quote inside your dynamic query then you need to use two single quotes. When the query is built the two single quotes will turn into one single quote. It's similar to escaping a "\" with  "\\" in a file path with your C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create such table in my tempdb like this:

```
declare @tableName sysname 
set @tableName = N'testTable2'
DECLARE @FullQuery nvarchar(1000)
SET @FullQuery = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = ''' + @tableName + ''' AND xtype=''U'') ' + 
                   
                    'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' ([DateTime] SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL, [FeatureNbr] SMALLINT NOT NULL, [Value] FLOAT (53) NULL, [Bool] BIT NULL, 
                    CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'UC_',@tableName)) + ' UNIQUE (DateTime), 
                    CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'PK_',@tableName)) + ' PRIMARY KEY (FeatureNbr, DateTime)); ' 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @FullQuery;
```

The quote issue is in the if statement.

Comment: That was the problem. Now it works great. Thank you for this help!!

Comment: @coding my help was to point you in the right direction so you can find your issue as you didn't know how. Yes, I just could have gave you an answer, but wasn't the point as it doesn't help you understand.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  Yes I know, I was just writing a comment about that and your post was deleted. I did execute your code and got: `Query executed successfully` and `(1 row(s) affected)` and `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE` etc.. I am not sure if I am looking at the wrong place. It would be nice to know how to do this for next problems? It seems that no problems were found there?

Comment: That output should be the full query that would be executed. If you look at that output, you'd realize the issue above in this answer. Anytime you're having issues with dynamic queries, select them out so you can see what *would be executed*.

Comment: Yes I understand. I should then look at the whole result. If I post the beginning. It looks like this: `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = [testTable2] AND xtype=U) CREATE TABLE [testTable2] ` I am not sure how to see what is not supposed to be here?

Comment: You're missing quotes as mentioned above, `WHERE Name = [testTable2] AND xtype=U` you need to wrap `testTable2` in quotes `'` as well as `U`. You should be able to take that output string (query from my example) and throw it in a new window and run it. If it fails it will tell you why.

Comment: I see, the only strange thing that I think confuses me is where I write: `CREATE TABLE [testTable2]` There I don't use quotes? Perheps `Name=` actually itself should be written with quotes and `U` That is the problem perheps?

Comment: @coding when creating tables, the name itself doesn't have to be wrapped and cant.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Yes, I think I understand the difference now. I think `QUOTENAME()` confused me to think it actually created normal quotes but reading here now what is returned by that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 It was good to use this method to investigate what could be wrong. Thank you for that!